# How do I use variables after header() redirect?

Tags: php, mysql

I've spent ages trying to figure this out after reading guide after guide and I can't get it. I have 3 files - user.php, map.php and newaddress.php. I've only included what I understand to be the important bits to this issue. Happy to provide more info if needed.

user.php passes a "mapnumber" to map.php.

user.php

```
<form action="map.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="mapnumber" value="'. $row["mapnumber"].'"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="process" value="process"/>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="getmap">Process</button>
</form>
```

map.php receives "mapnumber" and generates a list of addresses from the database with matching "mapnumber". From map.php, user can add new addresses which take the "mapnumber" value and is processed in newaddress.php.

map.php

```
$mapnumber = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['mapnumber']);
<form action="newaddress.php" method="post">
<input class="" id="mapnumber" name="mapnumber" value="<?php echo $mapnumber ?>">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="addaddress" type="submit">Add Address</button>
</form>
```

newaddress.php adds the address to database with the "mapnumber" value and then redirects back to map.php where it SHOULD generate the list of addresses based on "mapnumber" but map.php doesn't pick up the "mapnumber" from newaddress.php and hence the list of addresses isn't generated.

newaddress.php

```
$mapnumber = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['mapnumber']);
header("Location: map.php");
exit;
```

Please help

Comment: What is `$mysqli->escape_string()` and are you looking for errors, that I am pretty sure must be there

Comment: Where are you passing the map number to map.php during the redirect?

Comment: How would `map.php` know about anything if you don't pass something to that file? Every request in PHP is a brand new request. It doesn't know what happened before.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson. All newaddress.php is for is to INSERT data into db and then redirect back to map.php. How do I pass the value from newaddress.php to map.php?

Comment: You can use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST in map.php and change in newaddress.php `header("Location: map.php?mapnumber=".$_POST['mapnumber']);`  Or yo can use http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Ok try a `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST,1) . '</pre>';` right after the `<?php` line, what does that show. Post the result into your question

Comment: @DaartKote. It worked!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the get variable like this:

`$mapnumber = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['mapnumber']);
header("Location: map.php?nr=". $mapnumber);
exit;`

Than in `map.php` you get get it by:
`$mapnumber = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['nr']);`

Comment: Using a string concatenation at that point without urlencode() will lead to problems when the variable has chars like &?/ or any other char that will break URLs.

Comment: I tried this but the process from user.php to map.php is broken since map.php relies on user.php to pass data to it and from newaddress.php to map.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies to store values in the remote browser.
But the real problem you encounter is that the Location redirect is just that. It tells the browser to load another URL.
You can add get requests to that Location redirect URL like that:

```
header("Location: map.php?mapnumber=".urlencode($mapnumber));
```

But please keep in mind that the default Location redirect will be a permanent one (HTTP Status Code 301) and it is up to the browser to recheck if the redirecting url/document might have changed or not.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#78470

So you might want to consider using a 307 redirect:

```
header("Location: map.php?mapnumber=".urlencode($mapnumber), TRUE,307);
```

Anyway: passing variables from one page to another is generally not a good practice. Try to avoid it and try to dig into sessions.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: I tried using session variable. Not sure if I was doing it wrong but I've read that header(location) clears the session variables. Is that right? Whats the work around?

Comment: Do you have sources for that? A location redirect does occur in the users browser. That has no effect on server side stored session vars. You might have forgotten to write session data to the server before redirecting and stop executing the running php script

Comment: If you don't terminate the php script it might continue to run the rest of the code after a location redirect. Try to add die(); after you do a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use get method in map.php 
Then it will receive map number like `map.php?mapnumber=somenum`

user.php

```html
<form action="map.php" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="mapnumber" value="'. $row["mapnumber"].'"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="process" value="process"/>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="getmap">Process</button>
</form>
```

map.php

```html
$mapnumber = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['mapnumber']);
<form action="newaddress.php" method="post">
<input class="" id="mapnumber" name="mapnumber" value="<?php echo $mapnumber ?>">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="addaddress" type="submit">Add Address</button>
</form>
```

newaddress.php

```html
$mapnumber = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['mapnumber']);
header("Location: map.php?mapnumber=$_POST['mapnumber']");
exit;
```